# How to get a list of people who have checked into a place in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to use Facebook API to get a list of people who checked into a place.

When typing in the search box in Facebook UI `People who have been to THE_PLACE` I get a long list containing many people, also people who are not my friends or friends of friends.

However, when I try to get the same information from the Facebook API, I get a list that only contains my friends who checked in. The FQL I used is the following (and also some other variants that didn't do better): `SELECT author_uid FROM checkin WHERE target_id = THE_UID_OF_THE_PLACE`

Am I doing something wrong or is this simply impossible to get via API the same information I can access through the UI?

Comment: did you figure it out ?

Comment: It seems there's no simple way to do it. What I did instead is query according to coordinates (lat/long)

Comment: do you mean that you can retrieve a list of people (friends or not) who have checked in some coordinates? do you mind giving the FQL ?

Comment: This is the one I used. It retrieves posts that have location according to the filter: `/search?type=location&center=40.6700,-73.9400&distance=10000`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For privacy reasons, this is not possible at all. Also, FQL is deprecated. I have answered a similar question here: [facebook graph API - get last checked users to place/page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26911009/facebook-graph-api-get-last-checked-users-to-place-page)