# facebook graph API - get last checked users to place/page

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, checkin

I'm quite new to the FB API. In fact, I've just started. In my simple page I wanted to show a block dedicated to users, who recently (let's say for last 7 days) checked on my place. Is there any chance to do it through graph api? i have found several maybe not similar topics here but still usually there were no tips/solutions. Mainly i've found some issues with this concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs you can only check how many people checked in, but not who exactly: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page

...it does make sense though, for privacy reasons.

Comment: well.. fair point. is it the same with e.g. facebook likes? to show users who liked page for last 7 days?

Comment: yes, that´s not possible to get either - for the same reason (privacy). keep in mind that you can´t read everything with the api that is visible on facebook.com.

Comment: thanks for understanding and your support in this matter.